# Jquery mobile don't apply for the second load json

Tags: ajax, json, mobile

I using Opencart CMS. I was apply Opencart version Mobile by using Jquery mobile.
All page working very well but Checkout page.

Jquery mobile working for the first load and no Modify. But when i choose "Modify" button and Submit it. The next page (Load via Ajax) will don't apply css and js.

I have tried using .page() , .trigger(create) methods ... and got nowhere.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a multi-page template.

When I call $.mobile.changePage() the page loads just fine at first. On the second call the CSS is not loaded (or painted properly).